# react-native InputText onChange returns undefined or doesn't allow to change the value

Tags: react-native

I have the following code:

```
const { state, updateParentName, updateBabyName } = useContext(AuthContext);
const [isParentInputVisible, setParentInputVisible] = useState(false);

const toggleParentInput = () => {
  setParentInputVisible(!isParentInputVisible);
};

<View style={styles.headerContainer}>
  <Text style={styles.header}>Hello, </Text>
  {isParentInputVisible 
  ? (<TouchableOpacity onPress={toggleParentInput}>
      <Text style={styles.headerLink}>{state.parentName}</Text>
    </TouchableOpacity>) 
  : (<TextInput
      value={state.parentName}
      style={styles.parentInput}
      onChangeText={(value) => {updateParentName(value);}}
      onSubmitEditing={toggleParentInput}
    />)}
</View>;
```

And, as you can see, I use a Context to store my `parentName` value. I also set this var to `parent` as my default value.

Now, the problem that I am having and, that is driving me crazy, is **I can't change the value** in this Input field to anything. When I try to enter a new value there is returns `undefined`. When I remove `onChangeText` prop from that input for the sake of testing, it doesn't allow me to change the default value.

Can anyone point me to what should I do to fix it? I couldn't find anything useful that would help me.

**UPDATE:**

`AuthContext` file:

```
import createDataContext from './createDataContext';

const authReducer = (state, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case 'update_parent_name':
      return { ...state, parentName: action.payload };
    default:
      return state;
  }
};

const updateParentName = (dispatch) => ({ parentName }) => {
  dispatch({ type: 'update_parent_name', payload: parentName });
};

export const { Provider, Context } = createDataContext(
  authReducer,
  {
    updateParentName,
  },
  {
    parentName: 'parent',
  }
);
```

and, just in case `createDataContext` code:

```
import React, { useReducer } from 'react';

export default (reducer, actions, defaultValue) => {
  const Context = React.createContext(defaultValue);
  const Provider = ({ children }) => {
    const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(reducer, defaultValue);

    boundActions = {};

    for (let key in actions) {
      boundActions[key] = actions[key](dispatch);
    }
    return (
      <Context.Provider value={{ state, ...boundActions }}>
        {children}
      </Context.Provider>
    );
  };

  return { Context, Provider };
};
```

Comment: Can you share the code for updateParentName ? or you context file ?

Comment: @GuruparanGiritharan I've update original post, thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error is you've taken object as an argument in this function `updateParentName` but while calling the function through prop `onChangeText` you've passed the value as is without enclosing it in an object!

```
const updateParentName = (dispatch) => ({ parentName }) => {
  dispatch({ type: 'update_parent_name', payload: parentName });
};

onChangeText={(value) => {updateParentName(value);}} //passed only value not in an object!
```

Just change the onChangeText prop as such

```
onChangeText={(value) => {updateParentName({parentName:value});}}
```

Comment: Thank you! Even I'm new to `react-native`, very glad to have helped you out!